# How to know if network interface is in dhcp or static ip using command line?

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, static-ip

Using one or two command line, how do we know a particular `network interface` (e.g eth0) is connecting using `dhcp` or `static` ip?

can we do this using similar commands like `sudo cat`?

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` should list that out. If entry for your interface is something like `iface eth0 inet dhcp` where eth0 is interface, it could wlan0 for wifi or any other interface. For static, it should read out `iface eth0 inet static`.

Comment: @dastaan mine is `iface eth0 inet manual`  , what does `manual` means? same as `static`? I am looking for a script based solution to determine the Pi's networking methods (in this case, first find out if is `dhcp` or `static `)

Comment: Go through this answer on the unix SE. Link : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax Each option in `interfaces` file is explained in great detail. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does it work? If it does why do you care. The link @dastaan posted is probably irrelevant if you are using a recent image. What version? If you want help post `/etc/network/interfaces` in full as well as version.

Comment: @Milliways You might be true as this might not apply to newer jessie images.

Answer (score 1):

Examine processor status for a process by the name dhclient. Usually its pid will be listed under /run/dhclient..pid.

This process will not be run on statically configured addressed interfaces

Example: On a DHCP addressed eth0 RPi.

root      1711     1  0 07:58 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases 
eth0

root@homerpi:/# ls -l /run/dhclient.eth0.pid 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Nov 19 07:58 /run/dhclient.eth0.pid

Or as suggested earlier, examine the /etc/network/interfaces for its ip address
assignment mode

You could try /usr/bin/awk '/eth0/' /etc/network/interfaces